# Exponential Persistence and minimum steps, and the probability distribution.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, probability-distributions, recreational-mathematics, discrete-optimization

After looking at additive and multiplicative persistence, I wanted to look at a possible exponent extension.

I decided the most logical procession that left a "root" would be to take each digit to the power of it's position such that

$E_1(982)=9^3+8^2+2^1=795$

$E_2(982)=E_1(795)=7^3+9^2+5^1=429$
$\cdots E_7(982)=1$

Repeatedly until one digit remains gives the root, similar to the digital root.

$E_n(982)=1$

And the number of steps it takes to reach a one digit answer, or the persistence.

$E_p(982)=7$

Iterating this until a single digit remains takes 7 steps and results in the number 1.

Below is a table of the smallest integer k, with persistence n

$$ \left[
\begin{array}{cc}
n&k\\
  0&1\\
  1&10 \\
  2&19\\
  3&43 \\
  4&67 \\
  5&83 \\
6&92 \\
7&293 \\
8&691 \\
9&958 \\
10&7849 \\
11&49670 \\
12&94976 \\
13&880096 \\
14&7090761 \\
\end{array}
\right] $$

Also  $E_n(k)=1$ at least for the table above, but is this true for all k?

Unfortunately my limited python skills leads to a pretty inefficient search.

So my questions would be.

Is there a function that solves for k? What is the probability of getting a certain digit as the root? What about persistence?

Comment: The next 3 values in your table (15-17) are 80890670, 798992994, and 9999069559. It should be noted that the ending value for 798992994 is 2, since it generates 86088800, 17094528, 882986, 295727, 60092, 7859, 2947, 768, 387, 98, 89, 73, 52, 27, 11, 2.

Comment: Link to the OEIS sequence when it's added.

Comment: Currently awaiting approval

Comment: It has been approved for OEIS https://oeis.org/A298487